# Python parserError converting string to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large string value that needs to be converted to dataframe. I am using stringIO as a wrapper to then convert into dataframe using read_csv. Here is my code:

```
t4 = str(t3, 'utf-8')  #String Output

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(t4)) #wrap in stringIO and convert to dataframe
```

This throws the error

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 33 fields in line 30025, saw 34
```

I do realize this is due to bad data in the original string object, but what is the way to process this? I tried pasting to clipboard and reading from there, to no avail.

Comment: I guess you'll have to copy it to a file and fix the file before importing.

Comment: Can't you just write the string to file, process/remove the specific line throwing the error ?

Comment: @VikashB - this prevents me from automating it since I need to run it daily at a given time

Comment: You can still automate it, write it to a temporary file, fix/ignore the lines throwing the error and continue processing. Because ultimately, there is no way to recover from bad formatting errors unless you write your own parser, or use a custom parser that allows you to skip errors.

Comment: please post the output to e.g. `lines = t4.splitlines()[30022:30027]`